# Counting number of primes $p$ less than $x$ with certain constraints on prime divisors of $p-1$ for Artin's Conjecture on primitive root

Tags: analytic-number-theory, sieve-theory

I was reading this [paper](http://www.mast.queensu.ca/~murty/gupta-murty.pdf). There is a **Lemma 1** saying that for a fixed prime $q$ the cardinality of the set $\{p \leq x \mid (\frac{q}{p})=-1\}$ such that all odd prime divisors of $p-1$ are greater than $x^{\frac{1}{4}-\epsilon}$, is at least $\frac{cx}{\log^2x}$ where $c>0$ is some constant.

Its written in one of the cited source that it follows from **Theorem 1** of Rosser Seieve paper by Iwaneic (citation is mentioned in the original paper). But I don't understand how to do that. Could anyone please work out details for me ?

Comment: It is complicated due to the "least odd prime divisor" term. Why would you want such an estimate ? And with the quadratic reciprocity, $(\frac{q}{p})$ becomes $(-1)^{(q-1)/2}\chi(p)$ where $\chi(n) = 1_{n \equiv 1 \bmod 2} (-1)^{(n-1)/2} (\frac{n}{q})$ is a Dirichlet character modulo $4q$, so that $1_{(\frac{q}{p}) = -1} = \frac{1+(-1)^{(q-1)/2}\chi(p)}{2}$

Comment: Sir, in the paper that estimation is used later to find a primitive root from $S$. That's why I want to see the proof of $Lemma 1$ which is what I just wrote in the problem. Could you please elaborate more ? and even without $(\frac{q}{p})=-1$ is their easier way to achieve that lower bound ?